# How do you get the width and height of a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array defined:

```
int [,] ary;
// ...
int nArea = ary.Length; // x*y or total area
```

This is all well and good, but I need to know how wide this array is in the `x` and `y` dimensions individually. Namely, `ary.Length` might return 12 - but does that mean the array is 4 high and 3 wide, or 6 high and 2 wide?

How can I retrieve this information?

Answer (score 375, accepted):

You use [Array.GetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) with the index of the dimension you wish to retrieve.

Comment: `.Rank` for the number of dimensions. In the case this is 2, `.GetLength(0)` for the number of rows, `.GetLength(1)` for the number of columns.

Answer (score 196):

Use GetLength(), rather than Length.

```
int rowsOrHeight = ary.GetLength(0);
int colsOrWidth = ary.GetLength(1);
```

Answer (score 73):

```
// Two-dimensional GetLength example.
int[,] two = new int[5, 10];
Console.WriteLine(two.GetLength(0)); // Writes 5
Console.WriteLine(two.GetLength(1)); // Writes 10
```

Comment: Best example. Much more intuitive than the others. Just shows how the thing actually works.

Answer (score 35):

Some of the other posts are confused about which dimension is which.  Here's an NUNIT test that shows how 2D arrays work in C#

```
[Test]
public void ArraysAreRowMajor()
{
    var myArray = new int[2,3]
        {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6}
        };

    int rows = myArray.GetLength(0);
    int columns = myArray.GetLength(1);
    Assert.AreEqual(2,rows);
    Assert.AreEqual(3,columns);
    Assert.AreEqual(1,myArray[0,0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(2,myArray[0,1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(3,myArray[0,2]);
    Assert.AreEqual(4,myArray[1,0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(5,myArray[1,1]);
    Assert.AreEqual(6,myArray[1,2]);
}
```

Answer (score 29):

```
ary.GetLength(0) 
ary.GetLength(1)
```

for 2 dimensional array

Answer (score 6):

You could also consider using getting the indexes of last elements in each specified dimensions using this as following;

```
int x = ary.GetUpperBound(0);
int y = ary.GetUpperBound(1);
```

Keep in mind that this gets the value of index as 0-based.