# Row and column size for a 2-D array

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

The below listed code is to help me find the row and column size for a 2-dimensional array in C#, but I end up with a IndexOutOfRangeException when accessing the column-length(GetLength(1)). I did look-up similar [s.o q-a's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260207/how-do-you-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-c), but could not figure out the column size.

```
  List<List<int>> intLists = new List<List<int>>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      tempList.Add(j + 5+i);
    intLists.Add(tempList);
  }

  int[][] intArray = intLists.Select(Enumerable.ToArray).ToArray();

  Console.WriteLine("Dimension 0 Length = " + intArray[0].Length);
  Console.WriteLine("Dimension 1 Length = " + intArray[1].Length);
  Console.WriteLine("Dimension 0 Length = " + intArray.GetLength(0));
  //Console.WriteLine("Dimension 1 Length = " + intArray.GetLength(1));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`intArray` is an array of arrays, it is not a 2D array. `Array.GetLength` works only with multidimentional array (`int[,]`) because `intArray[0].Length` may be different from `intArray[1].Length`

Check this answer for more details:

[What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c)