# Why does my method continue past the length of the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I have been struggling with this for a couple hours now and I finally got this method to almost work except for the fact that it always goes 1 entry past the length of the array. How can I fix this?

```
public static string FillContestArray(string[,] talentCodes)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < talentCodes.Length; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < talentCodes.Length; y++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter contestant's name: ", x + 1);
                talentCodes[x,y] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter contestant's talent: ", y + 1);
                talentCodes[x,y] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        return talentCodes[x, y];
    }
```

Edit: People are asking for more details. Below is the rest of the code. What I am trying to do is pass the array contestants to this method FillContestArray in order to fill the array and then keep going from there. The user decides how big the array is if that is relevant at all. Sorry for the lack of detail or proper terminology, I am very new. Thanks!

```
int userInput = 0;
        int thisYear, lastYear;

        Console.Write("Please enter the number of contestants entered in last year's competition: ");
        lastYear = EnterContestants(userInput);
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of contestants entered in this year's competition: ");
        thisYear = EnterContestants(userInput);

        ContestMessage(thisYear, thisYear);

        string[,] contestants = new string[thisYear,thisYear];

        FillContestArray(contestants);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static int EnterContestants(int entries)
    {
        int numbOC;
        string numbString;
        numbString = Console.ReadLine();
        numbOC = Convert.ToInt32(numbString);

        return numbOC;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: the length property of an array only works for the first dimension. You should be using rank.

Comment: Your x and y are incremented inside loop. So while returning, you are over limit of your array

Comment: Your code has other problems though, like overwriting values in the second read line.

Comment: Could you explain more about what the code is trying to achieve?  As noted, there are many issues with the code, and it's difficult for us to assist you in fixing it if we don't know what the end goal is.

Comment: @Trevor I am trying to fill an array using this method. Sorry for lack of detail, I'm am very new to coding and this is my first time posting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the width and height of a multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260207/how-do-you-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some guesses from the updated code as to what you are trying to achieve ...

When you create the array of contestants with `string[,] contestants = new string[thisYear,thisYear];`, it creates an array of `thisYear` squared number of elements.

For example, if there are 5 contestants in this year's competition, `contestants` will contains 25 elements

```
contestants[0,0]
contestants[0,1]
contestants[0,2]
contestants[0,3]
contestants[0,4]
contestants[1,0]
contestants[1,1]
...
contestants[4,4]
```

If I were to guess, I would imagine that what you actually intended was to to make an array with two elements per contestant, one for their name and another for their talent, such as:

```
contestants[0,0] = "Alice"
contestants[0,1] = "Dancing"
contestants[1,0] = "Bob"
contestants[1,1] = "Juggling"
contestants[2,0] = "Carol"
contestants[2,1] = "Hacking"
contestants[3,0] = "Dan"
contestants[3,1] = "Singing"
...
```

This could be achieved by creating a two-dimensional array of `number of contestants` by `2`, such as:

```
string[,] contestants = new string[thisYear, 2];
```

This array would then be passed in to your modified `FillContestArray()` function to prompt for the name and talent for each of the contestants to be entered, as follows:

```
public static void FillContestArray(string[,] talentCodes)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < talentCodes.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter contestant's name: ", x + 1);
        talentCodes[x,0] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter contestant's talent: ", x + 1);
        talentCodes[x,1] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Note that the return type of the function is now `void` which means the function doesn't need to return a value, it only populates the array it was given.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

As your for-loops are over, the last value of x and y are `talentCode.Length()`. As the for loop terminates, when x and y are equal to `talentCode.Length()`. This is 1 element after the array, as it is counted from 0 to `talentCode.Length()-1`. If you now `return talentCode[x,y]`, you already use indices after the array.

By the way, it seems that you actually want to

```
return talentCode;
```

which will return the array, instead of

```
return talentCode[x,y];
```

which is invalid (trying to return the length+1,length+1 entry), compared to

```
return talentCode[x-1,y-1];
```

which will actually return the last element of your 2-dimensional array (see above explanation)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the two dimentional array length  - see this question for an example: [How do you get the width and height of a multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260207/how-do-you-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: Ok I think I understand the idea there but it seems when I implement it I baiscally have the same problem. So I'm assuming there is something I am still not getting