# Searching a two dimensional object array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have declared a two-dimensional object array as

```
object[,] sectionOpenings = new object[20, 4];
```

The first column is populated with string types, whilst the remaining three columns are all integers.

I wish to do a quick search to find a row with a matching string in the first column and have tried this

```
var first = Array.Find(sectionOpenings, p => p == "homedepot");
```

I get the following error:

> Error  CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Array.Find(T[], Predicate)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Array.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=net-5.0) only works on 1-dimensional arrays

Comment: Instead of using a two dimensional array of disparate types, use a single dimensioned array of objects of a specific type (say a class with a string property and three integer properties).  The reason you are getting the error is that the types of the objects in your array are simply `object`.  Your predicate (the lambda `p => p == "homedepot"`) doesn't know what to do since `p` is an object and it doesn't have an `operator == (string)`.  At the very least (if you want to stay in value type land), use a `List<(string, int, int, int)>` or an array of tuples like that.

Comment: thank you @greenjaed.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter your code a bit to get what you what:

```
var first = Array.Find(sectionOpenings, p => p[0] == "homedepot");
```

this will look in each array row, the first column p[0] == "homedepot"

edit:
my bad, I thought about jagged arrays

Well its not a one liner, but you can create a method like so:

```
public static int GetMatchingRow(object[,] myArr, string findMe)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myArr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (myArr[i, 0] is string && myArr[i, 0] as string == findMe)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile and returns the same error that the OP got.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing to a dictionary to ensure type safety- like so:

```cs
var sectionOpenings = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
sectionOpenings.TryGetValue("homedepot", out var result);
```

However, if you are stuck using a `2D array`, you'll likely have to do this in two steps. One, you'll have to find the matching column. Two, you'll have to retrieve the column. Something like this could work:

```cs
object[,] sectionOpenings = new object[20, 4];

var firstRowMatch = Enumerable
     .Range(0, sectionOpenings.GetLength(0)) // Gets row indices
     .Where(row => sectionOpenings[row, 0].ToString().Equals("homedepot"))
     .First();

var result = Enumerable
     .Range(0, sectionOpenings.GetLength(1)) // Gets column indices
     .Select(column => sectionOpenings[firstRowMatch, column])
     .ToArray();
```

With this example, you will likely have to add some type checks and null checks to make sure that this doesn't explode with a NullReferenceException.

This is adapted from [returning a whole column from a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427527/how-to-get-a-complete-row-or-column-from-2d-array-in-c-sharp) and [getting the number of columns/rows from a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260207/how-do-you-get-the-width-and-height-of-a-multi-dimensional-array) on stack overflow.

PS. This assumes you're using `System.Linq`

Comment: I changed the object array to Dictionary @Ziv. It was the simplest and quickest